# Going the colocation route - Thoughts or suggestions on plan?

Tags: hp, dell, datacenter, blade-server, apache-mesos

We currently host around 200 customers website with cpanel at a datacenter we rent dedicated servers from. We also host two sites that do around 5 to 6m unique a day, which is distributed across 3 servers. Outside of that, we have 2 nameservers and a development server as well.

We've been having some serious issues with downtime and reliability of the current DC/Host, most recently with nearly 2 days worth of downtime on the main cPanel box last week. So we're in a position where we want to migrate off their systems as soon as possible.

We are likely going to go the colocation route at a different local datacenter and purchase the hardware. Ultimately we're going to be moving to a HA architecture cluster with DC/OS - Apache Mesos, but to start and to get everyone off the one server, we'll likely setup xenserver with HA and migrate the cPanel customers to that so we have some better redundancy if a drive goes down.
Here's what our general plan for hardware is.

- New HP blc7000 or Dell m1000e enclosure with redundant ethernet
  switches and power
- 8x Blade Server.
- 2x Intel Processors
- 48GB+ Ram
- 2x 500GB 10k to 15k HDD RAID 1 or SSD if the price       difference
  isn't huge.

I like going the blade route as it should give us room to expand, especially moving towards Mesos - DC/OS for HA and redundancy.
Basically i'm just looking for some comments or suggestions about this plan so far.
Also what sort of Mbps internet connection should we be targetting at the DC? Most all sites we host are general hosting, we currently utilize around 4.4TB a month if that helps.

We're really trying to be cost effective, with this build. Any thoughts if its possible to get the total cost out the door down to about 30k for everything?
Thanks!

Comment: I'd love to help with this from a design, hardware and provider perspective. It's a big question, but yes, it's possible to get the hardware and project going under that cost figure, assuming you're in the US and open to HP ProLiant equipment. My contact details are in my profile.

Comment: (via email, please)